# jQuery autocomplete keeps giving TypeError

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

been trying to figure out this one for hours, no luck.
The exact error according to firebug is: TypeError: items[0] is null
http://localhost:81/tab/resources/jquery-ui.js
Line 8488

and the code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="resources/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="resources/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php',
      minLength: 3
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="skills">Skills: </label>
<input id="skills">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
require("db.php");

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

$key = $_GET['term'];
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM sz55 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND ejszakak BETWEEN 1 AND 100");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $row['name'];
}

echo json_encode($data);

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Help please :D

Comment: From your code I can't see how $_GET['term'] is being sent to your PHP script please do you have more code you have not shown as related to this problerm

Comment: According to the documentation, it is not needed to tpye ?term=
link: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Once check `$key` value by `echo` after setting

Comment: try using a different jquery version and different jquery ui try this <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: ANd also make sure your sql query is working very well

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried all of this, nothing works.
Running the search.php gives me the correct query result, so that is OK.
Older jquery version is giving the same error as before.
And declaring $data to be an array before the while loop had no effect. :(

Comment: In browser try to open http://localhost:81/tab/search.php?term=a   then check for results

Comment: Okay if you are using Google Chrome make sure caching is disabled in Dev tools. To disable open Chrome developer tools, move to the Network Tab and tick Disable cache. That should do it.

Comment: hmm strange, $data[] = $row['name'] does not work but if I declare the array mayself, like: $data = array("name1", "name2", "name3") than the autocomplete fuction works just fine. What gives?

Comment: Then it's problem with your sql query results..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the problem was that I had special characters in my array wich came from the query. Simply adding mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8"); to the search.php solved the problem.